# How to optimize the SQL query to reduce the runtime?

Tags: python, sql, query-optimization

Below is a sample of the table structure I am using. The table almost contains 200 million records.

The `query_1` returns the distinct combination of col_1, col_2 and col_3. Then it is iterated over these combinations to perform another query.

Given that the table is huge, the run time for this execution is very high. I am looking to optimize this. Can someone assist me to optimize this?

```
query_1 = select distinct col_1, col_2, col_3 from my_table

query_2 = select count (distinct col_4) from my_table mt
          where mt.col_1 = {} and mt.col_2 = {} and mt.col_3 = {} and mt.col_4 > {}
```

```
combinations = #output_of_query_1, this contains nearly 200K rows

for val1, val2, val3 in combinations:
    # execute query_2
    # query_2 uses the the val1, val2, and val3 for to the my_table
```

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | ... | col_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | e | 1 | ... | ..... |
| a | c | e | 2 | ... | ..... |
| a | c | f | 3 | ... | ..... |
| a | d | e | 1 | ... | ..... |
| a | d | e | 2 | ... | ..... |
| a | d | e | 3 | ... | ..... |
| a | d | e | 1 | ... | ..... |
| b | c | f | 1 | ... | ..... |
| b | c | e | 1 | ... | ..... |
| b | c | e | 2 | ... | ..... |
| b | c | e | 3 | ... | ..... |

Comment: Your question is unclear, and is attempting to explain a SQL problem from a cursor/programming point of view.  Instead, please add sample input data along with the output, and explain how to get from point A to point B.

Comment: Can you maybe paste your code so we can understand better what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The two queries that you are describing can be expressed as a single aggregation query:

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3, count(distinct col_4)
from my_table mt
group by col_1, col_2, col_3;
```

This would be the fastest way to run the query, in most databases.  Many databases can then use an index on `(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4)` for the aggregation query.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that filter used in where clause can also slow down your query performance. For instance using wildcard [(more here)](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/) at the beginning of the searched text: ("like %test") can be a trouble due to the fact that it forces index scan resulting in less efficient behaviour. In addition to this, correlated subqueries can be an issue (don't know if it is used in your case).